# Count unique features of points in polygon

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon

I have a series of points with various fields in the attribute table such as car_id, time etc.,

I've created a hexagon vector grid, I want to count how many unique car_id's occur in one of the hexagon polygons.

Essentially a step further than points in polygon, if there are multiple points in a polygon where car_id = 25, the car_id = 25 would be counted once. The car_id count for a polygon using the sample data below would be 4

```
car_id = 25
car_id = 25
car_id = 25
car_id = 22
car_id = 22
car_id = 23
car_id = 24
```

My question is what is the most appropriate QGIS tool to achieve this? Would it be Count Unique Points in Polygon, in the processing toolbox?

Comment: I have exactly the same question. But unfortunately the "Count Unique Points in Polygon" tool is not available anymore in QGIS 3 (I'm using QGIS 3.10). Do you know an alternative method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your guess is correct - use 'Count Unique Points in Polygon' in the processing toolbox, using "car_id" as the "Class field".